# Invalid v4 service endpoint for content-service in DXA 1.7 website

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

I am using SDL web 8.5 and configured DXA 1.7 .net web application. I am new to DXA implementation. I have setup the discovery service and website in the same machine. After publishing the website, When i access the site i am getting below error.

Page Url : http://localhost:93/

```
**Server Error in '/' Application.**

Invalid v4 service endpoint for content-service 
  **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.InvalidServiceEndpoint: Invalid v4 service endpoint for content-service

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[InvalidServiceEndpoint: Invalid v4 service endpoint for content-service]
   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ODataV4ServiceEndpoint() +171
   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor() +74
   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider.get_Instance() +147
   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime..ctor() +35
   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.<>c.<.cctor>b__33_0() +31
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +242
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +14803897
   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.HttpModule.CreateRequestPrivateClaimStore(HttpSessionState session, ISet`1& templateReadOnlyClaims, ISet`1& templateImmutableClaims, ISet`1& templateSessionScopeClaims) +114
   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.HttpModule.PerformRequestStart(HttpApplication application, Boolean dispatchOdataRequest) +186
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +139
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +91
```

**DXA site Web.config entries:**

```
<add key="discovery-service-uri" value="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc" />

<add key="cid-service-proxy-pattern" value="/cid*" />
```

**Site Log file:**

```
2017-08-28 16:12:00,278 [1] INFO  - -------- Initializing DXA Framework v1.7.0.309 --------
2017-08-28 16:12:00,309 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Common.Logging.Log4NetLogger' for interface ILogger.
2017-08-28 16:12:00,340 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Caching.DefaultCacheProvider' for interface ICacheProvider.
2017-08-28 16:12:00,340 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider' for interface IContentProvider.
2017-08-28 16:12:00,356 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Navigation.StaticNavigationProvider' for interface INavigationProvider.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,887 [1] ERROR - Unable to retrieve context engine service uri from discovery service. No ContextServiceCapability found!
Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.InvalidServiceEndpoint: Unable to retrieve context engine service uri from discovery service. No ContextServiceCapability found!
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.Caller.ODataContextEngineServiceClient..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.ODataContextEngine..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider..cctor() in C:\Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Context\ContextServiceClaimsProvider.cs:line 35
2017-08-28 16:12:01,919 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider' for interface IContextClaimsProvider.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,919 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Linking.DefaultLinkResolver' for interface ILinkResolver.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,934 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor' for interface IRichTextProcessor.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,934 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IConditionalEntityEvaluator.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,950 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.BaseMediaHelper' for interface IMediaHelper.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,965 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver' for interface ILocalizationResolver.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,965 [1] INFO  - Using implementation type 'Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.BaseStaticFileManager' for interface IStaticFileManager.
2017-08-28 16:12:01,981 [1] INFO  - No implementation type configured for optional interface IUnknownLocalizationHandler.
```

Did anyone faced this issue?, please suggest the fix.

Comment: Seems there is no ContextServiceCapability service running, provide more details of what are the micro services you have installed and registered with your discovery.

Comment: Hi **@velmurugan**,
I have used quick install script to install the service ".\quickinstall.ps1 -enable-discovery -enable-context -enable-deployer-combined -enable-preview -enable-session -auto-register -discovery-url http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc".  

Following services are running in the machine.
1. SDL Web monitoring service
2. SDL Web discovery service
3. SDL Web deployer service
and all SDL Web Content Manager services

Comment: Use this command to see the registered all Capability details, "java  -jar discovery-registration.jar read"  list and verify ContextServiceCapability exist or not

Comment: "com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.DeployerCapability", "com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.WebCapability" & "com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.TokenServiceCapability".I think content service is not configured.

Comment: Try to add all your required Capability in the discovery service cd_stograte_config.xml and then run this command to register "java -jar discovery-registration.jar update"

Answer (score 2):

Note though that you also dont have Content service registered, this is different from Context service, both microservices should be running and should be registered capabilities in the Discovery service storage config. While you can work-around the context service, you must have content service running and registered.